# Вопрос по перемещению блоков при адаптиве

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Допустим в версии для декстопа есть блок текста, под ним блок картинок, а под ним блок музыки.
Так вот, а как сделать чтоб на мобильной версии блок картинок оказался в самом верху, а после него уже другие 2?

Мне на ум приходят только 2 варианта: спозиционировать его абсолютно (что я думаю неправильно) или сделать копию этого блока вверху с display:none, и делать display:block в мобильной версии.

Как на самом деле правильно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с помощью таблиц http://jsfiddle.net/4tscyydk/, если не подходит, смотрите в сторону flexbox. Если тоже не вариант, используйте jQuery)))

```
$(".text").insertAfter(".img");
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать немного проще и не использовать таблицу там, где она семантически не нужна.
http://jsfiddle.net/4tscyydk/3/ (я просто немного изменил предыдущий ответ)

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .img {
      float: left;
  }
}
```